# NUXT3 server/api params cause 500 error on production

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, http-status-code-500

I'm currently working on a NUXT3 project, I have a form that collects information and files and sends to the server/api before been posted to the relevant locations.

Locally this works as expected, but on production it stumbles on the query params been sent from the form to the server/api and causes a 500 status code.

I've added my **form.vue** and **server/api/form.ts** files below, if anyone can spot whats going wrong please advice as I'm going around in circles with this.

**pages/form.vue**

```
        let formData = new FormData();

        for( let i = 0; i < files.value.length; i ++ ){
            formData.append('files['+i+']', files.value[i] );
        }

        let requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }
        await fetch( '/api/form/submit' + '?' + new URLSearchParams(form), requestOptions).then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

**server/api/form.ts**

```
import slugify from 'slugify';
import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

    const queryData = getQuery(event)
    const bodyData = await readMultipartFormData(event)

    const apikey = 'xxx'
    const username = 'xxx'
    const password = 'xxx'
    
    const to = queryData.to
    const from = queryData.from
    const subject = queryData.subject
    const message = queryData.message

    const notify = queryData.notify
    const confirmation = queryData.confirmation
    const firstname = queryData.firstname
    const surename = queryData.surename
    const telephonenumber = queryData.telephonenumber
    const service = queryData.service
    const projectdescription = queryData.projectdescription

    let files: any[] = []
    
    if(bodyData) {
        bodyData.forEach((item) => {
            if(item.filename) {
                files.push(item)
            }
        })
    }

    /* Step 1 - Login */
    const login = async () => {

        let requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST'
        }
        await fetch(`https://www.filemail.com/api/authentication/login?apikey=${apikey}&username=${username}&password=${password}`, requestOptions).then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        }).then((data: any) => {
            //console.log(`Logged In ✓`)
            initialize(data)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error)
        })

    }

    /* Step 2 - Initalize */
    const initialize = async (data: any) => {

        let requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST'
        }
        await fetch(`https://www.filemail.com/api/transfer/initialize?apikey=${apikey}&logintoken=${data.logintoken}&to=${to}&from=${from}&subject=${subject}&message=${message}&notify=${notify}&confirmation=${confirmation}`, requestOptions).then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        }).then((data) => {
            //console.log(`Initialized ✓`)
            saveFile(data)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error)
        })

    }

    /* Step 3 - Save Files */
    const saveFile = async (data: any) => {

        const transferUrl = data.transferurl
        const transferId = data.transferid
        const transferKey = data.transferkey

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            let formData = new FormData()

            formData.append('files', new Blob([files[i].data], {type: files[i].type}))

            let requestOptions = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }
            await fetch(`${transferUrl}?transferid=${transferId}&transferkey=${transferKey}&runtime=html5&chunksize=5000000&thefilename=${ slugify(files[i].filename, { lower: true }) }&chunks=10&chunk=0&retry=0`, requestOptions).then((response) => {
                return response
            }).then(() => {
                //console.log(`${ slugify(files[i].filename, { lower: true }) } Uploaded ✓`)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.warn(error)
            })

        }

        complete(data)

    }

    /* Step 4A - Complete */
    const complete = async (data: any) => {

        const transferId = data.transferid
        const transferKey = data.transferkey

        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('transferid', transferId)
        formData.append('transferkey', transferKey)
        formData.append('failed', 'false')

        let requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }
        await fetch('https://www.filemail.com/api/transfer/complete', requestOptions).then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        }).then((data) => {
            //console.log(`Completed ✓`)
            campaignMonitor(data)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error)
        })

    }

    /* Step 4B - Campaign Monitor */
    const campaignMonitor = async (data: any) => {

        const username = 'xxx'
        const password = 'xxx'

        let requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(username + ':' + password),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'To': [
                    'xxx@xxx.com',
                    'xxx@xxx.com'
                ],
                'Data': {
                    'first_name': firstname,
                    'surename': surename,
                    'email_address': from,
                    'telephone_number': telephonenumber,
                    'service': service,
                    'project_description': projectdescription,
                    'downloadurl': data.downloadurl
                },
                'ConsentToTrack': 'Yes'
            })
        }
        await fetch('https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.2/transactional/smartemail/xxx/send', requestOptions).then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        }).then(() => {
            //console.log(`Sent ✓`)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error)
        })

    }

    login()

    return ''

})
```

**Network Headers:**

[image]

I've tried using query: `{form}` within the request, I've also tried new URLSearchParams(form) to send the params.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur due to an SSL certificate that is connected incorrectly
Go through any SSL Checker and you will see an error.
Fix it and the server requests will work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35634433)